# Sauté the Meta.SO tag [bug-reports]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The meta tag [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports)  is a very silly tag. Its tag wiki states:

> Bug reports are posts about the filing of bugs and how to go about them, what to include or when to invoke the necessary spirits.

This is fairly misleading, and looking through the questions in the tag, none of them meet the tag wiki. If anything, this entire tag should just be an FAQ about Meta.

I'd edit these out myself, but I don't want to bump 33 old posts to the active feed. Can we just kill it instead?

**Request rescinded.** It makes sense to keep this tag.

Comment: Added obligatory GIF - rollback if you want.

Comment: You're missing the entire second paragraph of that text

Comment: Why would we shallow-fry a tag anyway??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [bug-reports](/questions/tagged/bug-reports) is widely misused for actual bug reports. It's meant to be a tag for questions **about** bug reports. Since using the actual [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag for a question about a bug report is an improper use of the tag (a question *about* bugs is not a bug itself), those questions need a separate tag.

Comment: That may be its intent, but are there any instances of it being used for that? If not, I'd say that BURNiNATING is still the way to go.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Yes, there's plenty of them. Just look through the list.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There were 15 out of 27 questions that actually used the tag for its intended purpose.